# install mlpy 3.5.0 on mac 10.9 error.Please help me

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

The following is the error which I am getting. Please help me to fix it.

```
apple:mlpy-3.5.0 apple$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlpy.gsl' extension
cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c mlpy/gsl/gsl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found
#include "gsl/gsl_sf.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: you have to add the path `.../gsl` to your `INCLUDE` environment variable or simply pass `-I.../gsl` to the compiler

Comment: @SaulloCastro can you please post as answer or should i?

Comment: What exactly worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

MLPy depends on GNU Scientific Library (GSL), which you need to install first.

You can install it either with `brew install gsl` or manually from source.

For manual installation, instructions can be found [here](http://www.brianomeara.info/tutorials/brownie/gsl). The relevant steps are as follows:

> - go to: http://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html
> - click on an ftp link close to your location
> - find the gsl/ directory and click on it
> - find the gsl-VERSION.tar.gz file, where version is 1.14 or greater. Click on that file to download it.
> - In a terminal window extract the tar.gz file using tar -xzf gsl-VERSION.tar.gz and then cd to the ./gsl-VERSION directory
> - Look at the INSTALL file. It will probably tell you to run ./configure, then make, and then make install (and you might have to
>     login as the superuser (sudo)

Answer (score 1):

I am actually getting the same issue today while installing mlpy. Based on the mlpy documentation. Here is the method to solve this issue.

According to the installation section in the mlpy documentation:

> If the GSL header files or shared library are in non-standard locations on your system, use the --include-dirs
>   and --rpath options to build_ext:
>
> $ python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/path/to/header --rpath=/path/to/lib
>
> $ python setup.py install

We have to assign the header and lib. Based on [How to obtain and install GSL](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC110/gsl/gsl.html),

> Under Search Paths/Header Search Paths type /opt/local/include
>
> Under Search Paths/Library Search Paths type /opt/local/lib

**The quick answer is running the below command:**

> sudo python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/opt/local/include --rpath=/opt/local/lib
>
> sudo python setup.py install

Hope this will be helpful.