# How to install mlpy for Python 3 in macOS

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I am trying to install [mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/install.html) for Python3 (I need to use its implementation of the Dynamic Time Warping algo.) but I can't get it to work.

The same package can be installed using Python 2.7, on the same machine, without problems, so I don't think that is an OS-related problem.

Any help is very welcome!!

```
# userx @ COG148 in ~/Downloads/mlpy-3.5.0 [12:09:06] 
$ python3 setup.py install                                            
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlpy.gsl' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/userx/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/userx/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/userx/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -I/Users/userx/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/userx/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c mlpy/gsl/gsl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found
#include "gsl/gsl_sf.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Of course, I have `gsl` installed on my machine (iMac with macOS 10.12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running

`python3 setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/usr/local/include/ --rpath=/usr/local/lib/`

followed by `python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably gcc has failed error comes when we don't have python headers not installed. You may try :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Try installing the header libraries for python 3 and then respond.

Comment: I have python3 installed via miniconda and I would like to keep that one as my default python. Is there any other option?

Comment: the above command is for python3 headers to be installed globally, so you can use headers inside minconda also. Please try installing.

Comment: did you tried installing the package with with **conda install package-name**

Comment: And if you are again facing the same error you may try below link, basically what we are doing is trying to access GSL header files/any type of shared libraries which are currently might be present in non-shared locations on your system since you have installed GSL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769648/7996581

Comment: conda doesn't have this package... Thanks for the links, I have tried what has been suggested in that post but no success yet